# How do I make a shared library for SharedPreference?

Tags: android, android-studio, shared-libraries, sharedpreferences

I am working on an application that has a lot of modules in it, and I need to load data from a `SharedPreference` class that I made called `SharedPrefManager` in the `:app` application which is the application where I implement the other modules into a module called `:mediplan` where I just want to retrieve the ID that I saved in the `SharedPrefManager`.

I tried to implement the dependency in the module in question `:mediplan` but I ended up with a lot of errors so I went back and took off the dependency.

The `SharedPrefManager` class:

```java
package com.example.tuteur;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

public class SharedPrefManager {

    private static final String SHARED_PREF_NAME = "CIN";
    private static final String IDCONT = "con";
    private static final String malade = "malade";
    private static SharedPrefManager mInstance;
    private static Context ctx;

    public SharedPrefManager(Context context) {
        ctx = context;
    }
    public static synchronized SharedPrefManager getInstance(Context context) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new SharedPrefManager(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public void setIdCont(String id) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = ctx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(IDCONT, id);

        editor.apply();
    }

    //this method will give the logged in user
    public String getIdCont() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = ctx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPreferences.getString(IDCONT, null);
    }



    //this method will give the logged in user
    public void setMalade(String malade) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = ctx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(malade, malade);

        editor.apply();
    }

    //this method will give the logged in user
    public String getMalade() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = ctx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPreferences.getString(malade, null);
    }

    //this method will log the user out
    public void logout() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = ctx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution I found is to use put extras and put bundle instead of using the shared libraries